Virtual element is not calculated
I'm trying to display item texts in Fiori app Display Line Items in General Ledger (F2217). I've extended the standard CDS view with a virtual element, but the code calculating the virtual element is not called.
I've extended CDS view C_JournalEntryItemBrowser, and associated the extension to a custom CDS view containing a virtual element, as described in this blog article. The virtual element is calculated by class ZCL_ACCOUNTING_ITEM_TEXTS. This class implements interface IF_SADL_EXIT_CALC_ELEMENT_READ.
This is the code of method IF_SADL_EXIT_CALC_ELEMENT_READ~calculate:
MOVE-CORRESPONDING it_original_data TO ct_calculated_data.
LOOP AT ct_calculated_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<calculated_line>).
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ZZ_ZTID' OF STRUCTURE <calculated_line> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_component>).
  <fs_component> = 'Test'.
ENDLOOP.

The new column corresponding to component ZZ_ZTID appears in the Fiori app with blank values, and break points set in Eclipse are not triggered when querying the app.
This is the CDS view containing the virtual element:
@EndUserText.label: 'Query accounting document item texts'
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@ObjectModel.supportedCapabilities: [ #CDS_MODELING_ASSOCIATION_TARGET, #CDS_MODELING_DATA_SOURCE ]
@OData.publish: true
define view entity Z_I_ACCOUNTING_ITEM_TEXTS as select from  I_GLAccountLineItem
{
  key SourceLedger,
  key CompanyCode,
  key FiscalYear,
  key AccountingDocument,
  key LedgerGLLineItem,
  key Ledger,
  
  @ObjectModel.readOnly: true
  @ObjectModel.virtualElement: true
  @ObjectModel.virtualElementCalculatedBy: 'ABAP:ZCL_ACCOUNTING_ITEM_TEXTS'
  cast( '' as z_ztid ) as ZZ_ZTID,
  
  _SourceLedger,
  _CompanyCode,
  _FiscalYear,
  _JournalEntry,
  _Ledger
}


When you extend the view C_JournalEntryItemBrowser with the virtual element ZZ_ZTID directly, and then open the project FAC_GLV_GL_ACCOUNT_LINE_ITEMS in SEGW transaction, you get the error: Error related to element 'ZZ_ZTID' of entity 'C_JOURNALENTRYITEMBROWSER(CDS)': Transformation @OBJECTMODEL.VIRTUALELEMENTCALCULATEDBY on element ZZ_ZTID is not allowed in analytical views .
The same error can be found in /IWFND/ERROR_LOG transaction when $metadata call is executed from /IWFND/GW_CLIENT transaction
I believe it is the same reason, virtual element calculation is not triggered and no value is displayed for your scenario
I have extended another CDS view (which is not analytical) and associated the extension to a custom CDS view containing a virtual element and the calculation is triggered & value is populated correctly.
So, the short answer is virtual elements cannot be used in analytical CDS views.

CDS view C_JournalEntryItemBrowser is not analytical in our system. The annotation @Analytics: { dataCategory: #CUBE } is commented (neutralized) with the comment "consumption views should not have a @Analytics.dataCategory". I've regenerated the project FAC_GLV_GL_ACCOUNT_LINE_ITEMS in SEGW and did not get that error.

Also: C_JournalEntryItemBrowser was not extended with ZZ_ZTID directly, but with an association to a custom CDS view containing the virtual element.
